# Resetting file format default in Photoshop PS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

My photoshop CS5 has always saved in .PSD and back to the previously saved into folder.  Now it wants to default to bitmapped and to the Temp folder.  I didn't modify it to do this and I wish to return to the default PSD format and previous folder routine.  How can I set or reset the default PSD format.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset Adobe Photoshop preferences back to factory default by holding down Ctrl, Alt, Del while the application starts. This should fix your issue. Just know that you will lose all other personal settings as well.

Comment: Thanks,but have a LOT of personal settings...  I have found that adding a layer (even one without anything in it) results in default Photoshop PSD format being presented on file save.  I can work with that if there is no file preference for setting default formats.  Thanks again for responding.